# How to remove color from BottomSheet container in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have detected that in the Material version, as well as in Material 3, when configuring my BottomSheetScaffold, when partially showing the BottomSheet in its initial state without being expanded, it creates a black background in case I set the containerColor to transparent, and if I do not indicate colors it sets it to white.

It should be noted that this happens when a sheetShape is added, if there is no shape, there is no problem.

Here I show the BottomSheet when it is partially displayed without being expanded:

[image: Collapsed BottomSheet]

Here I show the BottomSheet when it is expanded:

[image: Expanded BottomSheet]

```
val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState (
    bottomSheetState = rememberStandardBottomSheetState()
)
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val bottomSheetState = bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState

BottomSheetScaffold(
    scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
    containerColor = Color.Transparent,
    sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 20.dp, topEnd = 20.dp),
    sheetDragHandle = null,
    sheetSwipeEnabled = true,
    sheetContent = {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {

            Icon(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(50.dp)
                    .weight(1f)
                    .padding(bottom = 10.dp)
                    .noRippleClickable {
                        scope.launch {
                            when (bottomSheetState.currentValue.name) {
                                "PartiallyExpanded" -> bottomSheetState.expand()
                                "Expanded" -> bottomSheetState.partialExpand()
                            }
                        }
                    },
                imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_btntoriigate),
                tint = redPastel,
                contentDescription = "Leaf"
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(4f)
                    .padding(
                        top = 10.dp,
                        start = 10.dp,
                        end = 10.dp,
                        bottom = 20.dp
                    ),
                text = "Hello BottomSheetScaffold!"
            )
        }


        Text(text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.", color = Color.DarkGray)
    }
) { content(it) }
```

Could someone tell me how to remove the black background that is generated, as I would like to not have that background to show only the sheet.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should add `containerColor` for `BottomSheetScaffold`. The White/Black is activity's window color as you have set scaffold as transparent and made BottomSheet curved.

Answer (score 1):

There is no black background being generated, what you see around the corners is whatever is located underneath the `BottomSheetScaffold`. By applying `paddingValues` to the `content` you restrict it to stay above the collapsed bottom sheet. I.e. it's

```
|       content         |collapsed bottom sheet|
|         containerColor(transparent)          |
|               black background               |
```

not

```
                        |collapsed bottom sheet|
                        |   black background   |
|                    content                   |
```

For a fix you could either:

- Set `containerColor` to match color of the `content`. You would not be able to see the `content` around the rounded corners.
- Not apply `paddingValues` directly, at least not for the `bottom`. In this case bottom part of the `content` might get covered by the bottom sheet.

Comment: The problem was the PaddingValues, which was the one that was generating that space, but I didn't realize that I had it applied in content. In this case, changing the containerColor to the background color was not valid because the background has different colors, in the photo there is one but according to the section it changes, so the box would be noticed. But the issue of PaddingValues is the valid solution, not to apply it directly.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have discovered, it is not a specific color, but if you pass the paddingValue to the content you pass to your BottomSheetScaffold, it will generate that space at the bottom of the screen.